# Import Column from CSV into existing MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I've got a **MySQL** table `Researcher` :

```
ID | FirstName | Surname | Email | Position | Summary | ... + many more columns.
```

And a **CSV** file with the columns:

```
Email | Summary
```

In the MySQL table, the `Summary` column is blank for all rows, the data currently exists in the CSV.

I would like to import the `Summary` column from the CSV file, into the MySQL table, using `Email` to match the rows.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: google "mysql load data infile" and "mysql update". Come back when you have problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction fancyPants.

I eventually solved it like this:

1. Created a new table in the DB called `Researcher_Temp` with columns from the CSV.
2. Used phpMyAdmin to import the CSV using LOAD DATA into `Researcher_Temp`
3. Ran the following query to add the summary data  from `Researcher_Temp` into my main `Researcher` table:

`UPDATE Researcher 
INNER JOIN Researcher_Temp on Researcher_Temp.Email = Researcher.Email 
SET Researcher.Summary = Researcher_Temp.Summary;`

I then deleted the Temp table.